# How to call XAML file from HTML file in Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, html, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing Windows Phone 8 app and I'm having the problem of calling XAML file from my HTML page.
I gone through this link 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/ccfc9fbd-5b34-4263-a81a-224f3d645b30/how-to-call-xaml-file-from-html-file?forum=silverlightstart

but not understood properly.
If someone have idea of this then help me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have html in Windows Phone 8 application.
The link you are following is not about Windows Phone development but it is about Web Silverlight Applications.

EDIT
Make sure you understand the difference between Silverlight for Windows Phone and Web Silverlight Application: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb404700(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb404700%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: yes its about silverlight..n i dont know about silverlight(i m not working on silverlight).but in my app i stuck here how to call that xaml page in my html file..if u know then pls help me..